# VirtualBox Ubuntu 12.04 (64-bit) Guest Not Recognizing Android Device

Tags: android, ubuntu, usb, virtual-machine, virtualbox

I've setup an Ubuntu 12.04 LTS 64-bit VirtualBox guest running on a Windows 7 host (also 64-bit) with the sole purpose of Android-based hacking, programming, debugging, etc. I've followed numerous guides and forums in order to have my VBox guest recognize my physical Android device via USB, but I keep getting the following error pop-up:

```
Failed to attach the USB device motorola XT926 [0228] to the virtual machine Android.

USB device 'motorola XT926' with UUID {REDACTED} is busy with a previous request. Please try again later.

Result Code: E_INVALIDARG (0x80070057)
Component: HostUSBDevice
Interface: IHostUSBDevice {REDACTED}
Callee: IConsole {REDACTED}
```

I've tried the following:

**Note that I've already uninstalled VirtualBox, reinstalled the latest version, installed the VirtualBox Guest Additions as well as the latest expansion pack**

1. Shutdown VM
2. Plug in Android device via USB and allow Windows to recognize it
3. Run "VboxManage list usbhost" to confirm that the device is being recognized by VBox and listed as "Available"
4. Edit VM settings to enable USB Controller AND USB 2.0 (EHCI) Controller.
5. Add filter for Motorola device (VendorID = 22b8) and set Remote option to "Any"
6. Unplug Android device
7. Start VM, login and wait for it to "settle"
8. Plug in Android device

I've also tried the following:

- echo Y into the old_schema_first config
- create 70-android.rules with the appropriate SUBSYSTEM, ATTR and MODE values set

The guest VM still does not recognize the Android device and abd doesn't list any when I issue the `adb devices` command.

Any help here would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If your device support adb wireless debug (like Nexus), use that. If not, you can install adbWiress, this app makes your device debugable through wifi (need root).